# Whip cream dispenser is not dispensing a thick cream

Tags: equipment, whipped-cream, whipper

1.) What is the problem, why it dispensed liquid cream.
I followed the instruction. Like, put the whip cream inside then put the charger in then shake the dispenser many times, then I remove the charger, and then try to dispense the cream but what went out is a liquid cream.

I'm thinking of the technical side.
Like, should there be any indicator or sign that I should stop shaking it, like if there is no sound of a liquid inside the canister?

When I tried it with the charger inside, it dispense a very soft whip and very close to liquid but at least there is a form but in a few seconds or maybe 1 minute, it went back to liquid.

2.) Is it designed for non-dairy cream or both dairy and no-dairy?

3.) Should I shake it up-side down as well?

4.) After shaking, should I rest it for few minutes before using?

5.) Should I use a cold cream?

6.) Should I have to put the dispenser in freezer before using it?

7.) Can I use a recently used charger?
Like for example, I used it then I removed it from the dispenser and then when I tried it it is not yet thick, then I will use it again while it is still cold and just used a few minutes ago.
Is there any possibility of explosion?

Thanks for all your help 
It's my first time to use it.

Comment: What kind of cream did you use when you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Your results match what I've seen the few times I accidentally poured in half-and-half instead of heavy whipping cream.  You get something that's stiffer than what went in, but not really anywhere near the stiffness you want out of whipped cream.

So, if you used anything other than heavy cream, that would be my first suspicion about what's wrong.

Another thing to check is the amount of cream you put into the dispenser.  Your system should have instructions telling you how full it should be when you charge it (or maybe a line you're supposed to fill to); make sure you're following that guidance.  Overfilling the dispenser can also result in disappointingly dribbly output.

---

For your other specific questions:

> 2.) Is it designed for non-dairy cream or both dairy and no-dairy?

The ones I've used are designed for heavy cream.  Perhaps there are non-dairy alternatives out there that do a good enough job of mimicking heavy cream that they can be used with unmodified dispenser/charger systems, but I've never used anything else successfully.

> 3.) Should I shake it up-side down as well?

I usually do, but if you're shaking it thoroughly it shouldn't make a dramatic difference like you're seeing.

> 4.) After shaking, should I rest it for few minutes before using?

No need, it'll work immediately as soon as you shake it a bit.

> 5.) Should I use a cold cream?

Cold (fridge temperature) cream definitely works; I've never tried anything else.  I'd say you should use cold, simply because letting your cream come to room temperature seems like it would invite food safety concerns, but I don't know for sure if warmer cream would cause the kinds of texture problem you're seeing.

> 6.) Should I have to put the dispenser in freezer before using it?

No need; it works fine with a room temperature dispenser.

> 7.) Can I use a recently used charger? Like for example, I used it then I removed it from the dispenser and then when I tried it it is not yet thick, then I will use it again while it is still cold and just used a few minutes ago. Is there any possibility of explosion?

You can't really use an already-used charger, simply because once you use a charger, the gas has escaped from it and there's no "charge" left.  There's no possibility of an explosion, though, it just won't work.